# How to install a patch for Eclipse PDT bug fix

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-pdt

I have problem when running using xdebug for PHP. The step over is not work.

I found in google there is a bug fix for 3.3.1 PDT. I found this page  https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=445903#c3 and then follow this link in the page
https://git.eclipse.org/r/34466. Then I issue the command

```
git clone git://git.eclipse.org/gitroot/pdt/org.eclipse.pdt
```

Then right click my PHP  project and select Team-> Apply patch, however eclipse cannot find the patch file. Should I  compile the code first or am I pulling the wrong git?

Thanks

Comment: It seems there's a confusion between using git with your project and patching your plugin.

Comment: Actually, I think I have pulled down the patch from git. And I am first time doing the patch. So is there any step to patch the PDT Plugin?

Comment: What I'm saying is that if you click on your PHP project you operate on your own project not on PDT unless you have the PDT project loaded AS the project.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I am not providing the clear information. Actually, I am using Eclipse with PDT. However, Eclipse can break when I tried to debug the project. However, the step over is not worked. Thus, I find the solution in google. And found the patch. However, when I tried to patch the project in Eclipse. I cannot find any patch file.

Comment: Sorry to keep going about this but there's a difference between using Eclipse WITH PDT to edit your own PHP projects or using Eclipse to EDIT PDT. Patching PDT means you want to modify PDT itself, not your own project. You need to open PDT code base in Eclipse, not your own project if you want to apply a patch to PDT. With using the Team/Apply patch menu you can apply patch to the opened project.

Comment: I download the Eclipse PDT patch. And I do not know how to patch it. I think I will tried to run maven in the downloaded folder and see what can I do.

Answer (score 1):

Patch was merged into master, so easiest way to "patch" is install latest nightly.

See also this thread: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/823451/

As an alternative, you can build own compilation:

1. Build with -DskipTests based on this tutorial: https://wiki.eclipse.org/PDT/Contributing#Quick_guide
2. Add local update site into your eclipse repository list: GITROOT/dev/org.eclipse.php-repository/target/repository
3. Install by help->install new software.